# How to access a subdomain of an IP address?

Tags: ip, subdomain

I have a website that is accessible only by IP address. How can I access a subdomain of that website?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 by the way.

Comment: One possible workaround is to use [xip.io](http://xip.io) per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370422).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add subdomain.website.com to your /etc/hosts file, pointing to that IP.

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by "subdomain" and what you mean by "accessible only by IP address".

If, say, you're trying to access `google.com` and `maps.google.com`, but for some reason your local DNS server doesn't have an entry for `google.com`, then you may as well query it for `maps.google.com` as they're separate entries (usually).

If you don't *have* a domain name for the website but instead only an IP address, then what does a "subdomain"  of that mean? Say you're browsing to `http://87.87.87.87`, what is a "subdomain" of that?

Finally, it is usually pointless trying to reach a subdomain by connecting to the same IP address, as subdomain matching at the webserver-level is done by looking at the headers sent by the client, which wouldn't contain any subdomain information if you're connecting by IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this IP address to your webserver as well if you are putting data into a particular directory and sharing the webserver with another website. If not, then you are just going to get the primary website and the subdomain will not do any good.